# Multiple transaction managers with @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions

1. We have base generic manager which
   is inherited by all managers. Base
   manager is annotated with
   @Transactional annotations.
2. There are 2 groups of transactional
   services:

   - `x.y.service1.*` - have to be managed by `transactionManager1`
   - `x.y.service2.*` - have to be managed by `transactionManager2`

**How can transactions  be configured without nessesity to override ALL transactional methods and specify transaction manager?**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public abstract class GenericManagerImpl<D extends IGenericDao, T extends BaseObject, PK extends Serializable>
        implements IGenericManager<T, PK> {

    protected D dao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(D dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void save(T object) {
        dao.save(object);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void remove(T object) {
        dao.remove(object);
    }


}
```

---

```
@Service
class UserManagerImpl
        extends GenericManagerImpl<IUserDao, User, Long>
        implements IUserManager {

// Everything is OK. User is managed by txManager1

}
```

---

```
@Service
class BillingManagerImpl
        extends GenericManagerImpl<IBillingDao, Billing, Long>
        implements IBillingManager {

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, value="txManager2") // <--have to override method only to specify txManager
    public void save(final Billing billing ) {
        super.save(billing);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, value="txManager2") // <--have to override method only to specify txManager
    public void remove(final Billing billing ) {
        super.remove(billing);
    }
}
```

---

Most probably i need to combine aop with @Transactional annotation.
Actually, what i want is: 
1) To be able to configure transactions (read only flag, propogation, isolation etc) with @Transactional annotation. 
2) define strategy to choose transaction manager outside of my classes (using AOP, for example)
 
x.y.service1.* -> use txManager1
x.y.service2.* -> use txManager2

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 12):

There is the possibility to [create your own annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes) as shortcuts for `@Transactional(value="tx1")`. (These can be used at class or method level)

from the reference documentation:

For example, defining the following annotations

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("order")
public @interface OrderTx {
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("account")
public @interface AccountTx {
}
```

allows us to write the example from the previous section as

```
public class TransactionalService {

    @OrderTx
    public void setSomething(String name) { ... }

    @AccountTx
    public void doSomething() { ... }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, i know that i can use meta annotation. But this is just simplifying of configuration. 
I will still need to override method and annotate it with annotation like @OrderTx

Comment: @BigDong through the [`@AliasFor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) mechanism introduced in Spring 4.2

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can define `@Transactional` at class-level

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = false, value="txManager2") 
class BillingManagerImpl ....
```

Comment: I have read only adn NOT read only methods in base manager.
I have 2 options here:

1) have class level annotation @Transactional(readOnly = true) and method level annotation @Transactional(readOnly = false) for every NOT read only methods

2) have class level annotation @Transactional(readOnly = false) and method level annotation @Transactional(readOnly = true) for every read only methods

In any case i will need to override method level @transactional annotations for services which have to managed by txManager2