# How to configure what transaction manager to use without having to override all @Transactional methods

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Long time listener first time caller.

We have an AbstractService.java class that contains common transaction logic. Not all methods in this class are transactional. The once that are, are annotated with spring's @Transactional annotation.

Now each implementation of AbstractService could potential have a different transaction manager. This can be configured in the concrete class by overriding the method in the abstract class and provide a different tx manager:

> @Transactional(value=TRANSACTION_MANAGER)

It is not possible to pass in the transaction manager name to the abstract class since "The value for annotation attribute Transactional.value must be a constant expression".

So there are, as far as I know, two ways to configure the transaction manager:

1. Override every single @Transactional method in the concrete class just to call the super method:

   ```
    @Transactional(timeout = 60, value = TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public String editEntity(Integer id, Integer columnPosition, Object value) {
   return super.editEntity(id, columnPosition, value);
   ```
2. Add the @Transactional annotation on the class level instead. This forces the non-transactional methods to be handled within a transaction, and as the non-transactional methods call other methods that are transactional we end up with a nested tx soup.

Is there a third option? Something like the now deprecated spring testing [@NotTransactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/NotTransactional.html) would do the trick together with option 2 above.

There was a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333133/multiple-transaction-managers-with-transactional-annotation) asked almost three years ago. Since a lot has happened with Spring since then do we have another option?

Neat though it is, the custom annotation answer does not address the question.

My question can be summed up by:

**How can transactions be configured without having to override ALL transactional methods only to specify the transaction manager?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you refactor the `AbstractService` into three classes:

- The first class is the current `AbstractService`, its interface, method signatures, etc, to remain binary compatible with any existing child classes, but all implementation has been removed.
- The second class contains all business logic that is transactional, and consequently it uses the `@Transactional` annotation (with the correct transaction manager on the class level).
- The third class contains all non-transactional business logic.

Now, you simply autowire the last two classes into the refactored `AbstractService`, which just delegates an incoming method call to the implementation that was moved into one of the newly created classes.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Would the second and third classes be abstract? The reason why the logic is in the AbstractService to begin with is so that the ConcreteClassA and ConcreteClassB can extend and access common logic. I'm trying to wrap my head around your answer. In the ClassA and ClassB scenario would those be your second class? In that case the main reason to have that structure to begin with would be gone since now the logic would need to live in both classes. I'm probably misunderstanding you here.

Comment: My idea is to refactor the AbstractService to be an abstract [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that delegates to two concrete classes, one transactional and one non-transactional. Thus, none of the classes that currently extend the AbstractService needs to be changed

Comment: I will accept this answer on the basis of refactoring to break out the transactional methods into their own class. That it in addition proposes a [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) solution, is an extra plus.

Comment: One other way of solving this is to extend AbstractService with Abstract[SpecificTxMngr]Service that overrides all transactional methods and specifies a different txmngr. Each concrete class needing a particual txmngr would then override the relevant abstract service. This isn't as design pattern orthodox as the accepted answer, but there comes a day in every developer's life when inheritance will need to be embraced. In my particular case the inheritance solution seems to fit the intent of AbstractService better.