# Set default Transaction Manager in @Transactional annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring Boot 2.x application with JPA/Hibernate and 2 separate Transaction Managers: 1 per-tenant and 1 application-wide. All entities, repositories and services are separated in different packages.

Whenever I use `@Transactional` in my services, I need to explicitly qualify the txManager as either `@Transactional(value = "tenantTransactionManager")` or `@Transactional(value = "applicationTransactionManager")`.

This is very verbose and error prone since they are just literal strings.

Is there a way I can set the Transaction Manager on the package level, so I don't have to explicitly set this on every usage?

Based on the answer given in [Multiple transaction managers with @Transactional annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333133/multiple-transaction-managers-with-transactional-annotation), I created a `@TenantTransactional` and `@ApplicationTransactional` meta-annotation, but this does not let me set the `readOnly` flag, which is necessary per-method.

Comment: Just add the `readOnly` and use aliassing with `@AliasFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333133/multiple-transaction-managers-with-transactional-annotation) and the fact you have already `@TenantTransactional` and `@ApplicationTransactional` you can simply use an [alias](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/spring-annotation-programming-model#attribute-aliases-and-overrides) for `readOnly`. Adding an alias can be done using `@AliasFor`.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("tenantTransactionManager")
public @interface TenantTransactional {

  @AliasFor(attribute="readOnly", annotation=Transactional.class)
  boolean readOnly() default false;
}
```

Ofcourse you can do this for other properties of the `@Transactional` annotation as well.

Answer (score 0):

To setup the default transation manager which will be used you can annotate your transaction manager creation bean with @Primaty, like:

> ```
>   @Primary
>   @Bean
>   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
>     return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
>   }
> ```